# Draw tables in PDF using Java

Tags: java, pdf

I need to draw tables in a PDF document. I tried using the PDFBox but it does not support drawing tables. Then I found a library [Boxable](https://github.com/dhorions/boxable) which has written on top of PDFBox and supports drawing tables. But I need to give the width and the Height of the Cell in code, which actually I cannot provide since the content is decided at the run-time since the data which need to be written in the tables is generated dynamically.

*The sample code shows how to create a cell in 'Boxable'*

```
       Row<PDPage> row = table.createRow(10f);
       cell = row.createCell((100 / 3.0f) * 2, fact[0] );
```

I have used iText which is the perfect solution for this. But since due to new License change I cannot use it in a Commercial product. Though the iText 2.1.7 comes with GPL/MPL license they advise not use them.

What alternatives do I have to solve this Problem?

Comment: I thought you could draw out a table by hand in PDFbox? Like, if you know the spacing and what not you can draw lines where needed on the page?

Comment: Yes, in PDFBox by hand we can draw Tables. But it does not support drawing tables like in iText.

Comment: Then maybe you should use iText? I am not sure I understand the issue. If you want to make a table, but cannot afford iText, and you know that PDFbox won't just draw a table outright, then you have your answer, I believe :/ Not what you want to hear, but you should be able to create a method where you give it numRows/numCols/colHeaders, and it will draw a table for you in PDFBox...

Comment: Yes, I could do it the hard way, The reason why I asked this question is if there is an alternative library(which is possible) which actually provides the functionality I could use that. :)  . If someone knows such an alternative library I think he/she would mention that. Otherwise I use go the Hard way.

Comment: Anyway with the information I have 'create a method where you give it numRows/numCols/colHeaders' is not that easy since the content might be a whole paragraph or just a number and the number of columns is variable could also be more than 50 columns. So need to decide how such an table should be rendered to a A4 size space.

Comment: You are aware that strictly speaking library recommendations are off-topic on stackoverflow?

Comment: I don't even understand what you're asking. If the content is decided at runtime, then get the length of the text and calculate the width from there.